# supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS) progress bar not shiwing up in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am learning AsyncTask in android and I am trying to add a list of string in ListView in a background Thread and simultaneously trying to update the progress bar. The problem is progressbar is not showing up but the app is working fine... The items are getting added one by one.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView mListView;
    private String[] texts = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
       // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>()));
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

   private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>{

       private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
       private int count =0;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
        mAdapter= (ArrayAdapter<String>) mListView.getAdapter();
           setProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
           setProgressBarVisibility(true);
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           for(String item:texts){
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(500);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               publishProgress(item);
           }

           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        mAdapter.add(values[0]);
           count++;
           setProgress((int)(((double)count/texts.length)*10000));
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
           setProgressBarVisibility(false);
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"All items added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you reformat the code?

Comment: Finally figured to use Ctrl+K to format it.

Comment: Where you defined code for setProgressBarVisibility?

Comment: in the onPreExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

The progress feature has been deprecate form API 21. Android 6.0 is API 23

### Update

You may have to use ProgressBar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.technologybord.android.asynctasklistview.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/progress_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mainList;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    private String[] texts = {
            "Apple","Mango","Peach","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon","Tomato",
            "Fred", "Jane", "Richard Nixon", "Miss America",
            "man", "woman", "fish", "elephant", "unicorn",
            "a", "the", "every", "some",
            "big", "tiny", "pretty", "bald",
            "runs", "jumps", "talks", "sleeps",
            "loves", "hates", "sees", "knows", "looks for", "finds",
            "and", "or", "but", "because",
            "Apple","Mango","Peach","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon","Tomato",
            "Fred", "Jane", "Richard Nixon", "Miss America",
            "man", "woman", "fish", "elephant", "unicorn",
            "a", "the", "every", "some",
            "big", "tiny", "pretty", "bald",
            "runs", "jumps", "talks", "sleeps",
            "loves", "hates", "sees", "knows", "looks for", "finds",
            "and", "or", "but", "because"
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mainList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>()));

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_spinner);

        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private int counter = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //super.onPreExecute();
            this.adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)mainList.getAdapter();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                progressBar.setMin(0);
            }
            progressBar.setMax(10000);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
            //setProgressBarVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            for(String item: texts) {
                publishProgress(item);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            adapter.add(values[0]);
            counter++;
            progressBar.setProgress((int)(((double)counter/texts.length)*10000));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All items were added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```